# App going background and auto lock

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any difference between- An iphone app going background and phone is getting auto locked

I am developing an iPhone app
My app resumes its uploading process when it return from background
But it is not working if unlocked from auto locked

What is the issue..I have tried alot,but could not figure it out..Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299746/difference-between-terminating-an-app-opening-the-task-switcher-and-auto?rq=1

Comment: @ Rajan - no this is not the issue..Please read the question carefully
And I have tried with applicationDidBecomeActive,it works in both cases also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS shuts down WiFi when the screen is off - which is good as far as battery savings.

So please check the wifi connection while uploading..

You can restrict the auto-lock or device resume through programmatically while uploading and enable auto-lock programmatically after done the upload process .

If the device is connected to a power source, then Wifi remains enabled, even if the device goes to sleep. If the device is not connected to a power source, then Wifi is disabled once the device goes to sleep.

This of course was by design in an effort to reduce battery consumption

Comment: Exactly what I needed...was thinking about complex solutions
Thanks man...+1